# Trying to parallelize quicksort to run on multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, quicksort

I have a quicksort algorithm that works fine, but when I try an parallelize it only the second half the array is being sorted, the other half is almost unchanged. And since I am new to parallel programming I have no idea why.
The solution I have is combined from different codes found online.
How do improve it so that he whole array is sorted?

```
public class foo {

  private static final int N_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  private static final int FALLBACK = 2;
  private static Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N_THREADS);

  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(int[] numberArray){
    if(numberArray == null && numberArray.length == 0){
      return;
    }

    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
    pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(numberArray, 0, numberArray.length-1, count));
  }

private static class QuicksortRunnable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Runnable {

    private final int[] values;
    private final int left;
    private final int right;
    private final AtomicInteger count;

public QuicksortRunnable(int[] values, int left, int right, AtomicInteger count) {

      this.values = values;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
      this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      quicksort(left, right);
      synchronized (count) {
        if (count.getAndDecrement() == 1)
          count.notify();
      }
    }

    private void quicksort(int pLeft, int pRight) {
      int pivotIndex = (pRight - pLeft) / 2 + pLeft;
      int pivot = values[pivotIndex];
      int j = pRight;
      int i = pLeft;

      while (i < j) {
        while (values[i] > pivot) {
          i++;
        }
        while (values[j] < pivot) {
          j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
          int temp = values[i];
          values[i] = values[j];
          values[j] = temp;
          i++;
          j--;
        }
      }
      if (count.get() >= FALLBACK * N_THREADS) {
        if (pLeft < j)
          quicksort(pLeft, j);
        if (i < pRight)
          quicksort(i, pRight);
      } else {


        if (pLeft < j) {
          count.getAndAdd(1);
          pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(values, pLeft, j, count));
        }
        if (i < pRight) {
          count.getAndAdd(1);
          pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(values, i, pRight, count));
        }
      }
    }
  }
~~~
My main function:
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int length = 1000;
    int[] toSort = new int[length];
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
      toSort[i] = rand.nextInt(length);
    }

    sort(toSort);

    boolean sortedFH = true;
    boolean sortedSH = true;

    for(int i = 0; i<length/2; i++) {      
      if (toSort[i] < toSort[i + 1]) {
        sortedFH = false;
      }
    }
    for(int i = length/2; i<length-1; i++) {
      if (toSort[i] < toSort[i + 1]) {
        sortedSH = false;
      }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("First half :" + sortedFH);
    System.out.println("Second half :" + sortedSH);
  }
}

Returns:
First half :false
Second half :true
```

EDIT: Removed a part of the program. I tried something, didn't work, forgot to remove it when posting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I think the results you are seeing are mainly because you are printing out the results before the sorting threads have finished. You need to wait for all the threads to complete before you check the results.

Based on your code, you can do this easily enough using your `AtomicInteger` count to block the `sort()` returning until all the threads have finished.

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(int[] numberArray) {
        if (numberArray == null || numberArray.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);
        pool.execute(new QuicksortRunnable<T>(numberArray, 0, numberArray.length - 1, count));

        while (count.get() > 0) {
            synchronized (count) {
                count.wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

As an aside, unless it is intentional, your algorithm looks like it is going to sort the array in descending order. I think you need to flip

```
        while (values[i] > pivot) {
          i++;
        }
        while (values[j] < pivot) {
          j--;
        }
```

to

```
        while (values[i] < pivot) {
          i++;
        }
        while (values[j] > pivot) {
          j--;
        }
```

The same applies to your checks at the end of the main method.

---

Your check on a null or empty array should be separated by an OR not an AND

```
        if (numberArray == null || numberArray.length == 0) {
           return;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I was just writing the answer, since I figured out that I was checking the array before the threads are done. I didn't know though, how to check if threads are done, thanks.
And yes I am ordering the array from highest to lowest.